# Scrolling header with two list views

Tags: java, android

I have a header section that I would like to scroll with a list view below. The problem is that I have a toggle below the header section that allows the user to switch between two list views. What would be the best way to have a header section scroll in sync with the two list views below?

Answer (score 0):

I can share a short overview to help you:

```
<ScrollView ..>
     <LinearLayout>
           <HeaderView></HeaderView>
           <ToggleButton></ToggleButton>
           <ListView></ListView>
           <ListView></ListView>
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The tricky thing is: You have to flip the visibility of the two listView by visible and gone in the toggle button.

1st click on toggle will make it

```
listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
listView2.setVisibility(View.Visible)
```

2nd click on toggle will make it

```
listView2.setVisibility(View.GONE)
listView1.setVisibility(View.Visible)
```

Comment: Wont the ListView inside a ScrollView cause issues?

Comment: Nope. It shouldn't cause any issue.